# Compress an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, compression

Lets suggest i have an three-dimensional array like that:

```
$cars[0][0][1] = "BMW";
$cars[0][0][2] = "MUSTANG";

$cars[0][1][0] = "FORD";
$cars[0][1][1] = "GOLF";

$cars[1][0][0] = "MITSUBISHI";
$cars[1][0][1] = "PORSCHE";
```

and i want to have all results of the last dimension in an one dimensional array like that:

```
$cars[0] = "BMW";
$cars[1] = "MUSTANG";
$cars[2] = "FORD";
$cars[3] = "GOLF";
$cars[4] = "MITSUBISHI";
$cars[5] = "PORSCHE";
```

Is there some kind of function or quick way that breaks an array down like this, or do i have to build a construct of for and foreach loops do realize that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Based on the array structure, your best bet would be loops, though a recursive function might be a better solution if the arrays are illogical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one liner for you, recursively walks the `$cars` array and stores the value in `$result`.

```
array_walk_recursive($cars,function($v, $k) use (&$result){ $result[] = $v; });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flatten the array just so that you can iterate easily over it, you can hide the fact that it's a multi-level array using SPL:

```
$carsIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($cars)
);
foreach($carsIterator as $car) {
    echo $car, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i just tested it and it works perfectly fine also. Thank you for your quick answer.